# Java Hash table linear probing

Tags: java

Hi I am having issues printing and/or adding entries to my hash table I am looking to handle collisions with linear probing. Could someone help me? This is NOT a school project or assignment, just for fun.

I am new to the Java programming language.

I cannot get all of the entries to output to the console and I am wondering where I am going wrong.

```
/**
 * File             :   ContactTable.java
 * Project          :   None
 * Programmer       :   Braiden Gole
 * First version    :   2020-05-20
 * Description      :   This is the implementation of a hash table algorithm. We will be
 *                      storing a record with three pieces of information for contacting
 *                      a customer that is: First name, last name, email.
 */
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.InputMismatchException;

 class ContactTable {

    /**     -- Class header comment
     *  Name        :   HashNode
     *  Purpose     :   This represents an entry in our hash table.
     */
    static class HashNode {

        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String emailAddress;

        int position;
        HashNode next;
    }

    /**     -- Class header comment
     *  Name        :   TableMapper
     *  Purpose     :   This class represents the operations that our hash table will be
     *                  able to carry out.
     */
    static class TableMapper {

        private ArrayList<HashNode> hashTable = new ArrayList<>();
        private final int KTABLELIMIT = 5;

        /**     -- Method header comment
         *  Method          :   initializeContactTable
         *  Description     :   This will add (null) markers so we can detect when a position
         *                      has been filled with an entry or not.
         *  Parameters      :   None
         *  Returns         :   None
         */
        private void initializeContactTable() {
            for (int positions = 0; positions < KTABLELIMIT; positions++) {
                hashTable.add(null);
            }
        }

        /**     -- Method header comment
         *  Method          :   hashMethod
         *  Description     :   This is the hash method to calculate the position at which the
         *                      record of contact will sit in the contact table. We will be
         *                      using the name field to store the record.
         *  Parameters      :   key
         *  Returns         :   hashValue % KTABLELIMIT
         */
        private int hashMethod(String key) {

            int hashValue = 0;
            for (int letters = 0; letters < key.length(); letters++) {
                hashValue += key.charAt(letters);
            }
            return hashValue % KTABLELIMIT;
        }

        /**     -- Method header commment
         *  Method          :   insertRecord
         *  Description     :   This method will insert the entire object record into the
         *                      has table. We will handle collisions with linear probing and
         *                      make use of the "wrap around method."
         *  Parameters      :   key, position lastName, email
         *  Returns         :   currentSize
         */
        private int insertRecord(String key, int position, String lastName, String email) {

            HashNode checkPosition = hashTable.get(position);
            HashNode newRecord = new HashNode();

            // Check to make sure that the name does not already exist.
            while (checkPosition != null) {
                if ((checkPosition.firstName.equals(key)) == true) { return 1; }
                checkPosition = checkPosition.next;
            }

            // The calculated position has been moved, recalculate.
            checkPosition = hashTable.get(position);
            if (checkPosition == null) {
                newRecord.firstName = key;
                newRecord.position = position;
                newRecord.lastName = lastName;
                newRecord.emailAddress = email;
                newRecord.next = checkPosition;
                hashTable.add(position, newRecord);
                return 0;
            } else {
                while ((hashTable.get(position)) != null) {
                    ++position;
                    position %= KTABLELIMIT;
                }
                newRecord.firstName = key;
                newRecord.position = position;
                newRecord.lastName = lastName;
                newRecord.emailAddress = email;
                newRecord.next = hashTable.get(position);
                hashTable.add(position, newRecord);
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /**     -- Method header comment
         *  Method          :   showContacts
         *  Description     :   This will display all contact records to the console.
         *  Parameters      :   None
         *  Returns         :   None
         */
        private void showContacts() {
            for (int entries = 0; entries < KTABLELIMIT; entries++) {
                if ((hashTable.get(entries)) != null) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(hashTable.get(entries).firstName);
                    System.out.println(hashTable.get(entries).lastName);
                    System.out.println(hashTable.get(entries).emailAddress);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TableMapper mapper = new TableMapper();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        // The primaryKey is the users first name.
        String primaryKey = "";
        String lastName = "";
        String email = "";

        int index = 0;
        int currentSize = 0;
        int returnInsertVal = 0;

        // Initialize the contact table with (null) markers.
        mapper.initializeContactTable();

        boolean contactEntryCondition = true;
        while (contactEntryCondition) {
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("Enter in your first name: ");
            primaryKey = reader.next();

            System.out.print("Enter in your last name: ");
            lastName = reader.next();

            System.out.print("Enter in your email address: ");
            email = reader.next();

            // Calculate the index at which the record will sit.
            index = mapper.hashMethod(primaryKey);

            // Use the calculated index to insert the record at the proper position.
            returnInsertVal = mapper.insertRecord(primaryKey, index, lastName, email);

            // When the table is full exit the loop and print the table.
            if (currentSize == mapper.KTABLELIMIT) { contactEntryCondition = false; }
            if (returnInsertVal == 0) { ++currentSize; }
            else { primaryKey = ""; }
            System.out.println(currentSize);
        }
        reader.close();

        // Output the contact records.
        mapper.showContacts();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I do realize that the size can be a problem. I am just testing with about 5 entries and ideally I would like 10 to 16.

Comment: Is it possible some strings are using the same hash value?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, some will have the same hash value but that should be taken care of by my while loop because I then look for the next available position and when (null) is reached we have an empty position while incrementing the position recorded so when it is stored it should have the updated index. Thanks for writing in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after each `hashTable.add(position, newRecord)` your underlying list (`hashTable`) grows in size by one

> [void add(int index, E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional > operation). **Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right** (adds one to their indices).

this messes up the "bookkeeping" that you do on the table.

in `showContacts()`, change the `for` line as follows:

```
for (int entries = 0; entries < hashTable.size(); entries++) {
```

and it will print all the elements inside the table.

you should rethink your implementation and use a "fixed size underlying list" (possibly an array) enlarging it **only** when it's necessary and rehashing when you do so.